# Is there a way to apply a newer chart style to charts in powerpoint using python?

Tags: python, charts, powerpoint, python-pptx

When I create a line chart using python-pptx the result looks like this:
[image]

I'd like to change the design of the chart to one of the newer styles. Like this one:
[image]

When I do this change manually, I am unable to save the pptx document. An error box shows up saying "An error occured when powerpoint saved the file!".

Is there a way to use the newer chart styles when creating charts with python or is there a way to save the pptx-file when adjusting the chart style manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Aspose.Slides for Python](https://products.aspose.com/slides/python-net/), you could change the default chart style and achieve the second chart appearance as shown below:

```py
# Hide the vertical axis line.
chart.axes.vertical_axis.format.line.fill_format.fill_type = slides.FillType.NO_FILL

# Set the color for grid lines. 
chart.axes.vertical_axis.major_grid_lines_format.line.fill_format.fill_type = slides.FillType.SOLID
chart.axes.vertical_axis.major_grid_lines_format.line.fill_format.solid_fill_color.color = drawing.Color.light_gray

# Set the horizontal axis color.
chart.axes.horizontal_axis.format.line.fill_format.fill_type = slides.FillType.SOLID
chart.axes.horizontal_axis.format.line.fill_format.solid_fill_color.color = drawing.Color.dim_gray

# Place the legend at the bottom.
chart.legend.position = slides.charts.LegendPositionType.BOTTOM

# Set chart text properties.
chart.text_format.portion_format.fill_format.fill_type = slides.FillType.SOLID
chart.text_format.portion_format.fill_format.solid_fill_color.color = drawing.Color.dim_gray
chart.text_format.portion_format.latin_font = slides.FontData("Times New Roman")
chart.text_format.portion_format.font_height = 14
```

I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.